# Neo4j API not returning all relationships

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using the Neo4j API to get all the relationship from a node, however it seems that neo4j is not returning all relationships.

To following code:

```
Node node = graphDatabaseService.getNodeById(nodeId);
for (Relationship relationship : node
    .getRelationships(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Left"))){
    nodes.add(relationship.getOtherNode(node).getId());
}
```

returns only 200 relationships

while

```
    for (Path position: graphDatabaseService.traversalDescription()
            .depthFirst()
            .relationships(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Left"))
            .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(1)).traverse(initial)) {

        nodes.add(position.endNode().getId());
    }
```

i am only able to get 100 paths.

To following graph is obtained from the visual web interface

[image: graph visualization from webadmin]

Comment: is nodes a set or a list? and the traversal-description has uniqueness constraints that default to node-uniqueness.

Comment: Its a Set but since I am adding the internal ID they are unique I assume